# How to read redux store from non React components?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am building my first [react native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) app with [redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/).

My `store` configuration is as follows

```
function configureStore(onComplete: ?() => void) {
  const store = autoRehydrate()(createMyAppStore)(reducers);
  persistStore(store, {storage: AsyncStorage}, onComplete);
  if (isDebuggingInChrome) {
    window.store = store;
  }
  return store;
}
```

I have an authentication `action` as follows

```
export function authentiate(credentials) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return LoginApi.authenticate(credentials)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json().then(function(json) {
          dispatch(onAuthSuccess(json));
      });
    })
    .then(response => { dispatch(getUserInfo()); })
    .catch(error => {
      throw(error);
    });
  };
}
```

My `getUserInfo` `action` is as follows

```
export function getUserInfo() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return LoginApi.gerUserInfo()
    .then(result => { dispatch(onGetUserInfoSuccess(result.json())); })
    .catch(error => {
      throw(error);
    });
  };
}
```

My authentication reducer is as follows

```
function auth(state: State = initialState, action: Action): State {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.AUTH_SUCCESSFUL :
    return [...state, Object.assign({}, action.auth)];
    default :
    return state;
  }
  return state;
}
```

The `LoginApi` is a simple `ES6` class. The `getUserInfo` requires details like `access token` and other parameters obtained from the `LoginApi.authenticate` call.

How do I read the authentication information from the `redux store` from a `non-react` component?

Answer (score 3):

The second argument to redux-thunk is `getState`

```
export function getUserInfo() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState() // or cherry pick what you need
    return LoginApi.gerUserInfo(state)
    .then(result => { dispatch(onGetUserInfoSuccess(result.json())); })
    .catch(error => {
      throw(error);
    });
  };
}
```

https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#composition

Which is just the `store`s own `getState` function.

http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#getState

you can export / import your `store` and call `getState` directly if you want.

```
let store = createStore(...)
export { store }

// anywhere.js
import { store } from './your-store.js'
let state = store.getState()
```

Comment: So does that mean I cannot access the store/state from any non-react components. Instead I should access them from the action and pass them as a parameter to the external components?

Comment: If you export your `store` (the one you created using `createStore()`) you can import that wherever you want and call `store.getState()`. doesn't have to be component. Your example, however, was using a redux-thunk which has access to the store already. it's up to you